# How to stop a thread on application exit / class destruction?

Tags: java, multithreading

Heres my thread:

```
class A
{
    private class MeshBuilder implements Runnable
    {
        private volatile boolean looping = true;

        public void run() 
        {
            Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.OFF, "starting new thread");
            while(looping)
            { 
            }
            Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.OFF, "closing thread");
        }

        public void endLoop()
        {
            looping = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried overriding host class finalize function, but process stays in memory. ( I think garbage collector calls original finalize, not mine )

```
class A
{
    ...

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable 
    {
        meshBuilder.endLoop();
        super.finalize();
    }

    ...
}
```

If I want that thread to end (call endLooping) when host class (A) dies or when application finishes executing, how do I do that?

---

@Brett Okken

I have added:

```
private class MeshBuilderShutdownHook implements Runnable
{
    MeshBuilder meshBuilder;
    public MeshBuilderShutdownHook(MeshBuilder meshBuilder)
    {
        this.meshBuilder = meshBuilder;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.OFF, "MeshBuilderShutdownHook");
        meshBuilder.endLoop();
    }

}
```

And in class A constructor I have:

```
    meshBuilder = new MeshBuilder();
    meshThread = new Thread(meshBuilder);
    meshThread.start();

    MeshBuilderShutdownHook shutdownHook = new MeshBuilderShutdownHook(meshBuilder);
    Thread shutdownThread = new Thread(shutdownHook);
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownThread);
```

And when I close my application, the thread is still running.

/\ adding meshThread.setDaemon(true); solves it

Comment: Not with `finalize`. This is called by the GC, at some point. Possibly never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It somewhat depends on what your runtime is. If you have a traditional jse environment, you can [register a shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).
If you are in a servlet container, you can use a ServletContextListener to be told when the [context is destroyed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29).

Comment: I have traditional environment, but how will hook thread know about meshBuilder instance? I have tried passing meshBuilder to hookThread in constructor, and then calling endLoop in hookThreads run method with no result.

Comment: The `Thread` that you register as a shutdown hook would need have runnable implementation which has reference to your `meshBuilder` instance to shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

finalize method : *Called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object. A subclass overrides the finalize method to dispose of system resources or to perform other cleanup.* (javadoc).

so when class A ends, it doesn't necessarily mean that JVM's garabage collector would have run.

a *not so good way* to do it:

`for(i=1;i<=2*1000;i++)
{
System.gc();
}`

but this should be done in some other class' method, only then object of A will be collected by garbage collector(on which finalize will be run by garbage collector, *IF* JVM invokes GC thread).